# How to trace <script> elements/errors with Codeception with phantomjs/Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, phantomjs, codeception

I've set up acceptance tests with codeception and phantomjs.
My website contains script elements:

```
<script src="/bla/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The JavaScript file looks like this:

```
Bla = {
    request: function(var) {
    }
};
```

It looks like the content cannot be found since one of the buttons contains

```
onclick="return Bla.request('100')"
```

Running the acceptance test which clicks on this button shows me:

```
[Selenium browser Logs] 
  17:10:24.876 WARNING - SyntaxError: Parse error

  17:10:25.121 WARNING - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Bla
    onclick (http://localhost/bla)
Screenshot and page source were saved into '/var/www/bla/_output/' dir FAIL
```

Does the first parse error already mean that the files have been loaded but contain errors? If so, how can I see the exact parse errors?

Requesting the JS file manually in the acceptance test works and it is the correct file (as the output shows):

```
$I->amOnPage('/bla/test.js');
```

I run codeception with the option --debug and looked at the output files where everything looked correct. How can I see if the JavaScript file has been imported correctly and if the parse error means that it failed, how do I get more information about the error?

edit:
Even if the parse error is not present I cannot access variables from a different JavaScript file.
When I have multiple script elements:

```
<script src="/bla/test0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/bla/test1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Bla
```

in file test1.js if it was defined in test0.js. This works in the normal browser without errors.

Comment: How are you clicking on the button?

Comment: $I->click('buttonname'); and nothing happens/the javascript code is not called because of the syntax error I guess. The button is an <a> element with the onclick attribute.